# Gradle script to append timeStamp to files

Tags: build.gradle

Very simple question but somehow does not work !
First time working with Gradle
The task is to write a gradle task that iterates files in a directory and prefixes timeStamps to the fileNames.

I have a script but when I run Gradle with the target, fileNames are sometimes listed and sometimes not. No changes to directories done!
The exclude is to exclude the files that were renamed earlier - basically regex to check files starting with digits.

Here is a script

```
task renameSqlFiles(type: Copy) {

from "${rootDir}/migration/resources"
into "${rootDir}/migration/resources"

include '**/*.sql'
exclude '^\\d+__.sql'
rename { fileName -> println(fileName)

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def getDate() {
    new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS')
}

task renameForMigration() {
    println(" :migrate : renameForMigration")
    def files = fileTree(dir: "${rootDir}/migration/resources/sql", includes: ['V*.sql'])
    doLast {
        files.each { file ->
            def newFileName = "${getDate()}__${file.getName()}"
            ant.move(file: file, toFile:"${file.parent}/${newFileName}")
            sleep(1000)
        }
    }
}
```